# SharePoint activate feature file not found error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, feature-activation

I am trying to activate a feature on our production MOSS server, all I get is a file not found exception.

Feature works great in test environment. What can it be?

Comment: Are you able to update the question with any more detail as we don't have much to go on here. Can you give a full stack trace? Have you checked the SharePoint ULS and Windows Event logs?

Answer (score 0):

Has your feature file been deployed to the production server's file system?

Comment: Used a WSP Package to ship the feature.

Comment: Are there platform differences between test and production? Maybe one is 32 bit and the other is 64 bit?

Comment: @drivendevelopment: This 32/64-bit *shouldn't* matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool such as [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to discover exactly which file is not found. This will give you some clues.

I've experienced this problem when deploying a solution to a server with an over-eager virus scanner. This blocked use of the temp directory which was needed for extracting files from the WSP file.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked. Delete and recreate the site.